# Do I need a template class to pass a method to base class?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, inheritance

I am writing a finite state machine (FSM) class, which should be inherited from various other derived classes (as a part of an Arduino project).
The derived classes need to pass boolean methods to the base FSM class trigging state changes. The methods are kept in a map. When called in the main loop they go thru the methods in the map to see whether a state change applies.

Since the FSM class needs to call methods of the derived classes I wrote the FSM class as template class based on the class of the derived class. The object to apply the method on (T& obj) is passed to the constructor:

```
template <class T> class FiniteStateMachine {
public:
  FiniteStateMachine(int numberOfStates, int initialState, T& obj);

  typedef bool (T::*TransitionCondFunction)(void);
  void addTransition(int fromState, int toState,  TransitionCondFunction transitionFunction);

  void loop();

private:
  int _numStates;
  int _state;

  T& _obj;   // the object to apply the functions on
  map<int,map<int,TransitionCondFunction>> _transitionMap;
}

template<class T>
FiniteStateMachine<T>::FiniteStateMachine(int numberOfStates, int initialState, T& obj) :
_numStates(numberOfStates), _state(initialState), _obj(obj), _transitionMap() {}

template<class T>
void FiniteStateMachine<T>::addTransition(int fromState, int toState,  TransitionCondFunction transitionFunction){
  _transitionMap[fromState][toState] = transitionFunction;
}

template<class T>
void FiniteStateMachine<T>::loop(){
  auto it = _transitionMap.find(_state);
  if (it != _transitionMap.end()){
    map<int,TransitionCondFunction> innerTransMap = it->second;
    for(typename map<int,TransitionCondFunction>::iterator iter = innerTransMap.begin(); iter != innerTransMap.end(); ++iter) {

      bool (T::*tf)(void)  = iter->second;
      // is condition for transition fullfilled?
      if ((_obj.*tf)()) {
        int toState =  iter->first;
        // ok, transit to next state
        _state = toState;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Cannot find transition condition function for state %d\n", _state);
  }
}
```

A concrete derived class would like this:

```
enum MyState {STATE0, STATE1, STATE2, NUM_STATES};

class MyTransitionClass : public FiniteStateMachine<MyTransitionClass>{
public:
  MyTransitionClass(int numberOfStates, int initialState) :
    FiniteStateMachine(numberOfStates, initialState, *this){
    addTransition(STATE0, STATE1, t1);
  }
  bool t1(){return _x>0;}

private:
  int _x = 99;
};
```

And the usage (within a unit test) would be this way:

```
TEST(FiniteStates_test, testWithInheritedClass){

  MyTransitionClass mc = MyTransitionClass(2,STATE0);
  EXPECT_EQ(STATE0, mc.getState());
  mc.loop();
  EXPECT_EQ(STATE1, mc.getState());
}
```

This works, but I wonder whether there are other options. It simply does not "feel" optimal to instatiate a template class with the derived class as template type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `It simply does not "feel" optimal`? In my opinion it completely feel legal and optimal to use derived type as template argument to base template class.

Comment: Well, I would probably replace the member function pointer by a function object instead which might be more flexible (I think it would allows lambda expressions). But I am not sure how it would compare from a performance point of view although for most application, it probably does not matters that much.

Comment: Why not just make addTransition() within the base class virtual, and override it in the derived classes?

Comment: If i made addTransition virtual and override it within the derived class, wouldn't I need the type again when i call it within the loop() function? So i would still need templates...